# Insert function within multiple reactive plots in R Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, dplyr

I would like to insert a function within the ggplot2 function for an interactive R Shiny visualization platform, and be able to keep the entire dataset and not have the data preprocessed.

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume that I want to take the mean of multiple groups.

In the pre-processed situation, I would take the mean of multiple groups, like so:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data_long %>%
  group_by(Variable, State, Scenario, Month) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(mean))
```

Taking the preprocessed dataset, I run it through the R Shiny platform:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Title"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("variableInput", "Variable",
                   choices = c("Income", "Electricity"),
                   selected = "Income"),
      uiOutput("stateOutput")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("coolplot"),
      br(), br(),
      tableOutput("results")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$stateOutput <- renderUI({
    selectInput("stateInput", "State",
                sort(unique(df$State)),
                selected = "New York")
  })  

  filtered <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$stateInput)) {
      return(NULL)
    }    

    df %>%
      filter(Variable == input$variableInput,
             State == input$stateInput
      )
  })

  output$coolplot <- renderPlot({
    if (is.null(filtered())) {
      return()
    }
    ggplot(filtered(), aes(x = Month, y = Value, group = Scenario, colour = Scenario)) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_point( size=4, shape=21, fill="white")
  })

  output$results <- renderTable({
    filtered()
  })
}
```

Instead, I would like to have the `dplyr` grouping function be inserted into the ggplot portion in R Shiny and be able to keep the entire dataset. Any help would be appreciated. Questions and comments are welcome.

**Edit**

Instead of using the UI built for one plot, I'd also like to build a platform that supports multiple plots. For visualization purposes, it looks something like this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  h1("Title"),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 1.5, class = "panel",
           selectInput("State", label = "State", width = "100%",
                       choices = c("New York", "New Jersey", "Texas", "California")), 
           selectInput("Variable", label = "Variable",  width = "100%",
                       choices = c("Income", "Electricity"))
    ),
    column(width = 11, "Main Plot",
           highchartOutput("hcontainer", height = "500px"),
           fixedRow(
             column(3,
                    "Subplot 1",
                    highchartOutput("hcontainer",height = "500px")
                  ),
             column(3,
                    "Subplot 2",
                    highchartOutput("hcontainer",height = "500px")
                    ),
             column(3,
                    "Subplot 3",
                    highchartOutput("hcontainer",height = "500px")
                    )
           )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: And why would you want that? If it's not a reactive element, why do you need it inside the server code, let alone inside the ggplot() part? By definition of "reactive expression" it will be recalculated every time the plot is made. That sounds to me like a bad idea. But you just need to replace `df` inside your server function by `data_long %>% ...` you use outside of the server function. Then you keep the data and `filtered()` will still be correct.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The main reason why is so that the underlying functions can be reusable for many different data sets. I'd like for it to be a reactive element so that in the future I can write my own computations instead of using just the mean of a vector.

Comment: Then make the dataset `df` itself a reactive expression inside your server. But don't try to push it into the ggplot2 part, that really doesn't make any sense from a design point of view.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. How would I go about with doing that, and with multiple plots, each with their own specifications (for the sake of simplicity, mean, median, whatever)?

Comment: If you need multiple calculations on the same data frame, there's nothing that stops you from using the reactive expression `df()` in different parts of your code. I can't really help you more without more specifics, but if you work on a larger app where parts can be reused, you should really think about modularizing your code. See also http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html .

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks again!